# Which solution supplied zend_translate for translate word with few meanings?

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization, zend-translate

Which solution supplied zend_translate for translate word with few meanings?

Example: http://m-carstairs.com/englishlessons/id12.html

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1):

Just saw your edit. I do not think there is anything as good as it should be to interpret such nuances of the language. Google translate is as good as it gets as far as I know.

Comment: Where is translation of same word that have different meaning?

Comment: If you mean some way to differiate between to identical words qwell how do you imagine it could work?? Do you think zend_translate is like google translate? Because its not at all.

Comment: soo how do you suggest to translate?

Comment: Just saw your edit. I do not think there is anything as good as it should be to interpret such nuances of the language.

Comment: Ok, but if you have sensative data - you have t have correct translation 100% not 99%- and this google translate dont gives as far as I know

Comment: Its a much more difficult problem then you seem to think. Translating words like you suggests would imply that the software is interpreting the text. This is as of yet impossible in any reliable and bulletproof way. Its literally AI.